# Backup failed. Error received from server: Backup functionality disabled

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, error, backup

The following error message received when trying to install an M2 extension.

Backup failed
Error received from the server:
Backup functionality is disabled

[image: Magento 2 Backup functionality disabled]

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable Backup in admin
Stores -> configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Backup Settings
Set enable backup to Yes
Save config
Then flush cache. Link to it will appear at top of this admin page and 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it in two different ways:

## Via admin panel

**Stores > configuration > Advanced > System > Backup Settings**

[image: Magento 2 enabling backup via admin panel]

## Via terminal

```
php bin/magento config:set system/backup/functionality_enabled 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Backup setting by going to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Backup Setting in Magento admin.

OR

If you want to enable it with the CLI, you can use the below command:

```
php bin/magento config:set system/backup/functionality_enabled 1
```

DB backup: `php bin/magento setup:backup --db`

Code backup: `php bin/magento setup:backup --code`